Magnetization of an Electric Guitar String
I'm trying to calculate the magnetic field generated by electric guitar strings of various gauges. The strings are made of some ferromagnetic material (pure steel or pure nickel). They are magnetized by permanent magnets some distance away in the pickup.
I'm basically wondering if there is an equation that takes in the permanent magnets magnetic field strength, some constant (having to do with the material of the wire), the gauge of the wire, and the wire's distance from the magnet and outputs the magnetic field due to the wire.

There is no magnetic field due to the wire; there's only a small disturbance in the field produced by the magnet inside the pick-up. Nothing is induced here either. Maybe if you tried to explain what your ultimate goal was, you might get a more useful response.

@Andy aka Of course there's induction: how do you imagine the pickup works? The usual way to analyze this is to calculate the "reluctance" of the "magnetic circuit", treating the magnetic field as if it is fluid flow.

@JohnDoty please try and read the question carefully; the op said magnetism was induced and, there is no mention of the pick-up coil so, nothing is induced here (as in the contents of the question).

@Andyaka I believe your literal approach is causing misunderstanding. The pickup is a system that works through induction. Saying ""nothing is induced" is misleading. Perhaps you mean that the magnetization of the string is technically not via "induction"?

Read the question is my advice and don't try and extrapolate.
